# Is there a .d.ts file for Angular 1.3.x?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

I'd like to move an Angular 1.3.x app to Typescript 2.0, is there a .d.ts file for Angular 1.3?

Comment: did you try to check it?

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the repository: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/351589d38dcc4ba657e5b4e5af81cbf860ed00c1/types/angular (It's for angular 1.6)